# Akka.net Akka.IO TCP client large messages

Tags: akka.net

I'm using Akka.IO for a TCP client and when I try to send messages larger than around 77KB, it fails with no errors - the remote end does not get any response. Works just fine with all smaller messages. Tried changing some config parameters like io.tcp.direct-buffer-size, but no luck. What am I missing? Using version 1.0.5

Comment: What does your debug logging output say?

Comment: Nothing, even though I've configured io.tcp.trace-logging = on

Comment: Have you followed the instructions for how to configure the logging?

Comment: I see debug logs for all the other actors. Are you talking about instructions that are specific for io.tcp stuff?

Comment: @MishaK Are you using .NET CLR or Mono?

Comment: It's .NET CLR. I got the debug logs from TcpConnection. What seems to happen is if a message is over a certain size, I see the Channel.Write() with the correct number of bytes, immediately followed by a disconnect( Channel.Read() == -1) and the remote end never gets the data.

Comment: For people that run into similar issues - instead of spending more time figuring out this problem, I've stopped using Akka.IO and instead am using Akka.NET with Nancy self-hosting.